# NULL POINTER EXCEPTION of Cursor c

Tags: android, database, eclipse

```java
public abstract class AbstractIME extends InputMethodService implements 
KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener, CandidateView.CandidateViewListener {
    ...
    private void clearCandidates() {
        ...
        final dbhelper helper = new dbhelper(this);
        Cursor c = helper.query();
    }
    ...
}

public class CangjieDictionary extends WordDictionary {
    private AbstractIME ime;
    ....
    private String sortWords(char[] data) {
        ....
        dbhelper dbh = new dbhelper(ime); ;
        Cursor c = dbh.query();
    }
}
```

Here are two classes. For the first one is ok, no problem
but same code for the second class

the following is the logcat message  why there is null pointer for the second class?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
at com.googlecode.tcime.unofficial.dbhelper.query(dbhelper.java:50)
at com.googlecode.tcime.unofficial.CangjieDictionary.sortWords(CangjieDictionary.java:111)
```

Comment: Do you ever instantiate `ime`?  (with `ime = ...`)

Comment: private AbstractIME ime;

Comment: in fact i don't know what should i add of the context

Comment: @BoyKwok As sam mentioned, you seem to be missing instantiation for `ime`, something like: `ime = new AbstractIME();`.

Comment: I think the problem is not here. for initialize class, it is no necessary to add new....()  can I set the context be other things?

Comment: i identify that for the first one is activity but the second one may not be. So is it the problem? but I still not know how to solve

Comment: I have also try another activity class. the same code, but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `WordDictionary` declare a Context member and create a constructor that has a Context param

```
Context mContext;

public WordDictionary(Context context)
{
     mContext = context:
}
```

Then in `CangjieDictionary`

```
public class CangjieDictionary extends WordDictionary {
private AbstractIME ime;
....
private String sortWords(char[] data) {
    ....
    dbhelper dbh = new dbhelper(mContext);
    Cursor c = dbh.query();
}
```

}